# How to get divider line in function/option table in Wolfram Workbench

Tags: documentation, workbench, format

In the tutorial pages in the documentation to my package, I have a table that contains functions and their definitions.   In the sample tutorial page, I see a divider line separating the header from the rest of the rows in the table, which you can see:

[image]

How do I create one for my own tutorial page?  I can't seem to find it in the Documentation Tools palette.

Comment: You can always press Ctrl+Shift+E on any Cell to see "its source code". Just do this for that table in the EulerSum documentation, select the code and copy it to you tutorial notebook.

Comment: @vsht It works! Thanks.  Feel free to add an answer.